# Android: How do i send a file from my android app to a remote server which is on openshift?

Tags: php, android, openshift

what i'm trying to do is to save a file in a remote server which is created on openshift (i created an application with php 5.3). this is the code which sends a file:

```
private void postFile(){
        try{
        String postReceiverUrl = "https://openshift.redhat.com/app/console/application/537e9c0be0b8cd34170000b6-alldata";

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(postReceiverUrl);

    File file = new File(detail);
    FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file);

    MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    reqEntity.addPart("file", fileBody);
    httpPost.setEntity(reqEntity);


        HttpResponse  response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

        if(resEntity != null){
            String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity).trim();
            Log.v("MyApp", "Response:" + responseStr);
        }
        else Log.v("MyApp", "couldn't commnicate with the server");

    }catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        }
```

It throws an exception when it executes the following line:

```
HttpResponse  response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

this is the logcat message:

```
05-27 15:32:01.557: D/libEGL(18546): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX544_115.so
05-27 15:32:01.607: D/libEGL(18546): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX544_115.so
05-27 15:32:01.627: D/libEGL(18546): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX544_115.so
05-27 15:32:01.697: D/OpenGLRenderer(18546): Enabling debug mode 0
05-27 15:32:06.717: I/dalvikvm(18546): Total arena pages for JIT: 11
05-27 15:32:06.717: I/dalvikvm(18546): Total arena pages for JIT: 12
05-27 15:32:06.727: D/dalvikvm(18546): Rejecting registerization due to and-int/lit16 v0, v5, (#128)
05-27 15:32:06.737: D/dalvikvm(18546): Rejecting registerization due to and-int/lit16 v0, v5, (#128)
05-27 15:32:06.817: D/dalvikvm(18546): Rejecting registerization due to move v5, v4, (#0)
05-27 15:32:06.827: D/dalvikvm(18546): Rejecting registerization due to move v5, v4, (#0)
05-27 15:32:06.827: D/dalvikvm(18546): Rejecting registerization due to mul-int/lit8 v4, v2, (#31)
05-27 15:32:06.827: D/dalvikvm(18546): Rejecting registerization due to mul-int/lit8 v4, v2, (#31)
05-27 15:32:06.827: D/dalvikvm(18546): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicHeaderValueParser;.INSTANCE
05-27 15:32:06.837: W/dalvikvm(18546): VFY: unable to resolve static field 3758 (INSTANCE) in Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicHeaderValueParser;
05-27 15:32:06.837: D/dalvikvm(18546): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x001b
05-27 15:32:06.837: D/dalvikvm(18546): DexOpt: couldn't find static field Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicHeaderValueFormatter;.INSTANCE
05-27 15:32:06.837: W/dalvikvm(18546): VFY: unable to resolve static field 3752 (INSTANCE) in Lorg/apache/http/message/BasicHeaderValueFormatter;
05-27 15:32:06.837: D/dalvikvm(18546): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0015
05-27 15:32:06.857: W/System.err(18546): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
05-27 15:32:06.867: W/System.err(18546):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1128)
05-27 15:32:06.877: W/System.err(18546):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
05-27 15:32:06.877: W/System.err(18546):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
05-27 15:32:06.877: W/System.err(18546):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
05-27 15:32:06.877: D/dalvikvm(18546): Rejecting registerization due to +iget-quick v3, v5, (#20)
05-27 15:32:06.877: W/System.err(18546):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
05-27 15:32:06.877: W/System.err(18546):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
05-27 15:32:06.877: W/System.err(18546):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
05-27 15:32:06.877: W/System.err(18546):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
05-27 15:32:06.877: W/System.err(18546):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
05-27 15:32:06.877: W/System.err(18546):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
05-27 15:32:06.877: W/System.err(18546):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
05-27 15:32:06.877: W/System.err(18546):    at com.measuredistancewalked.PostData.postFile(PostData.java:108)
05-27 15:32:06.877: W/System.err(18546):    at com.measuredistancewalked.PostData.writeFile(PostData.java:82)
05-27 15:32:06.877: W/System.err(18546):    at com.measuredistancewalked.PostData.saveAllData(PostData.java:58)
05-27 15:32:06.877: W/System.err(18546):    at com.measuredistancewalked.DitanceWalkedActivity$1.onClick(DitanceWalkedActivity.java:74)
05-27 15:32:06.877: W/System.err(18546):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4383)
05-27 15:32:06.877: W/System.err(18546):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18097)
05-27 15:32:06.877: W/System.err(18546):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-27 15:32:06.877: W/System.err(18546):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-27 15:32:06.877: W/System.err(18546):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
05-27 15:32:06.877: W/System.err(18546):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
05-27 15:32:06.877: W/System.err(18546):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-27 15:32:06.877: W/System.err(18546):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-27 15:32:06.877: W/System.err(18546):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
05-27 15:32:06.877: W/System.err(18546):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
05-27 15:32:06.877: W/System.err(18546):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-27 15:32:06.887: D/dalvikvm(18546): Rejecting registerization due to +iget-object-quick v7, v9, (#8)
05-27 15:32:06.907: I/dalvikvm(18546): Total arena pages for JIT: 13
05-27 15:32:06.907: I/dalvikvm(18546): Total arena pages for JIT: 14
```

and I have the following post_file.php code :

```
<?php
if($_FILES){
$file = $_FILES['file'];
$fileContents =  file_get_contents($file["all_data_file"]);
print_r($fileContents);
}
?>
```

my question is :

where do i upload my php code? and

what else should i do to communicate with the server other than providing my openshift application url in my code?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Always include the logcat in your question if you get exceptions. Without the logcat it will be difficult to pinpoint the problem.

Comment: @XaverKapeller i included the logcat message. whenever i executed the above code it jumps to the 2nd catch block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app crashes always take a look at the logcat. In 99% of all cases the error message tells you exactly what's wrong and how you can fix it, just like in your case:

```
05-27 15:32:06.857: W/System.err(18546): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

You cannot perform complex tasks in the UI Thread, doing so would cause your app to freeze and lag. In Android there is an extra safe guard against this when it comes to networking. If you try to perform network operations on the UI thread an Exception is thrown, namely this `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

**Solution:** You have to perform your work in a separate `Thread`. I recommend you use an `AsyncTask` for this.
Take a look at this example for an `AsyncTask`, the method `doInBackground()` is executed in a separate `Thread`, you can perform all your work there. After `doInBackground()` has finished the result returned by it will be passed to `onPostExecute()`. `onPostExecute()` will again be executed on the UI Thread, so here you can return results from the `AsyncTask` to the UI.

```
private class ExampleTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

        // Do your work here

        // Return true if successful otherwise false
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if(result) {
            // Work has been completed successfully    
        } else {
            // Work was not completed successfully
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Xaver Kapeller. your answer was helpful. do you have any idea how do i send a file from android app to a remote server, openshift?

Comment: I'm glad I could help, unfortunately I have no experience with Openshift. Try asking a new question.

Answer (score -1):

You need to move network activity off of the UI thread, it should be handled in an `AsyncTask`.

```
private class upload extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {

    private void doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        try {
            String postReceiverUrl = "https://openshift.redhat.com/app/console/application/537e9c0be0b8cd34170000b6-alldata";

            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(postReceiverUrl);

            File file = new File(detail);
            FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file);

            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            reqEntity.addPart("file", fileBody);
            httpPost.setEntity(reqEntity);

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();

            if(resEntity != null) {
                String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity).trim();
                Log.v("MyApp", "Response:" + responseStr);
            } else {
                Log.v("MyApp", "couldn't commnicate with the server");
            }

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

You execute the `AsyncTask` like this:

```
new upload().execute(url);
```

Comment: Your answer is wrong. You obviously never tested this. 1) Your `doInBackground` has `void` as return type but your `AsyncTask` specifies `Long` as return type. 2) You never call return even once inside `doInBackground()` 3) Your class is called `upload` which is against convention. By convention all class names start with an uppercase letter and all methods and variables start with a lowercase letter. And on top of all that it is formatted terribly. I have already took care of correcting the formatting this time, but be more careful next time.